# Self-map of short exact sequences

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, short-exact-sequences

Consider the commutative diagram of finite abelian groups
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0@>>> A @>i>> B@>\pi>> C@>>> 0\\
\   @VV 0 V@VVfV@VV 0 V\\
0@>>>A @>>i> B@>>\pi> C@>>> 0
\end{CD}
where all maps are homomorphisms, the rows are exact, and the leftmost and the rightmost vertical map are zero? **Is the middle map $f$ also zero?**

It is clear that $f\circ f=0$ but this is all that  seems to follow from lazy diagram chasing, hence I suspect $f$ need not be zero, in general. If so, what is a counterexample?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take the sequence $0\to Z/2Z\to Z/4Z\to Z/2Z\to 0$ and the vertical map multiplication by 2.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I should have seen this myself.

Comment: Or take $0\to A\to A\oplus C\to C\to0$, then $f(a,c)=(h(c),0)$ for any homomorphism $h:C\to A$